# Another one "You don’t seem to have a generator with the name"

Tags: ecmascript-6, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to make a simple Yeoman generator in ES6.
I think I followed the [documentation](http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html).
After `$npm link`in the current folder of my generator i go in another directory and try :

```
? 'Allo Emmanuel! What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
Run a generator
❯ Starterpack
──────────────
Update your generators
Install a generator
Find some help
Get me out of here!
──────────────
```

My Generator seem to be avaible, but not :

```
Make sure you are in the directory you want to scaffold into.
This generator can also be run with: yo starterpack

Error

You don’t seem to have a generator with the name “starterpack:app” installed.
```

If needed all code are available here : https://github.com/ethyde/generator-starterpack

What I did wrong ?

Thanks.

EDIT : Fixed, thanks, I have updated the repo with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generator is not exporting a standard node module. See this line https://github.com/ethyde/generator-starterpack/blob/master/generators/app/index.js#L77

Babel by default compile es6 module files to `exports.defaults`. Yeoman expects a usual Node.js export. In other words, it expects your generator to be exported as `module.exports = Generator`.

You'll need to update your babel configuration.